# Contentful validation Error expected type:Array

Tags: c#, contentful

I am getting the following error when trying to upload a field in a list. Can not field any documentation on how to reslove this error so posting it here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more detail about your Object.

As per your questions and detail share by your, it seems that you have list of Array type  and while uploading you are not posting the array in the item. If it is correct than try to change your list to List type and than try.

Please paste your code snippiest, if possible, so that we have more clarity about the problem. but try to play with the List and than see, is there any change.

Comment: If you need more information or unsure about the answer, put in a comment seeking for more information or clarification.

Comment: Obviously, AKP can't because of not enough reputation.